# JavaScript file naming conventions when there is a space in the project name

Tags: javascript, naming-conventions

I have some JavaScript I want to make available for people to use. The JavaScript project is called, say, *Sharp Knife*. The key point is that it has a space in it.

How do I name the minified JS file of version 1.0 to be consistent with prevailing conventions?

- `sharp-knife-1.0.min.js`
- `sharp.knife-1.0.min.js`
- `sharpknife-1.0.min.js`
- something else?

Comment: "What's in a name? That which we call a rose By any other name would smell as sweet."

Comment: I don't get the votes to close the question as non-constructive. Surely, if it's all opinion because there simply is no prevailing convention, then an answer to the effect that there simply is no prevailing convention is a useful answer to a useful question. (Well, of course I think it's useful, since I asked it, but anyway...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use whatever you prefer. But please don't use spaces - they are ugly in URLs (and filenames imho)

I'd probably use a CamelCased filename, i.e. `SharpKnife-1.0.min.js`